# Delay directive/div until scope value available

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asynchronous

I have a custom directive for soundcloud that requires the soundcloud url. The soundcloud url is fetched from the database through the $http service, however, the div for the soundcloud custom directive is loaded and requires the value of the soundcloud url before it is even defined.

The Plangular Directive Code I got is here:
https://github.com/jxnblk/plangular/blob/master/src/plangular.js *I did not develop this

This is my HTML code:

```
<div plangular="{{soundcloud}}">
<button ng-click="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>
<progress ng-value="currentTime / duration || 0">
{{ currentTime / duration || 0 }}
</progress>
</div>
```

And this is the Angular Code:

```
displaySong.controller('song', ['$scope', '$http', 'fetchSong', function($scope, $http, fetchSong) {
    $scope.songID
    $scope.songName;

    //Controller properties
    $scope.songPromise; //The song promise for fetching

    $scope.init = function(songID, userID) {
        $scope.songID = songID;
        $scope.userID = userID;
        $scope.songPromise = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: fetchSong,
            data: {
                song_id: $scope.songID
            },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function(successResponse) {
            console.log('Successfully fetched song');
            console.log(successResponse);
            var song = successResponse.data;
            $scope.songID = song.song_id;
            $scope.songName = song.song_name;
            $scope.songType = song.song_type;
            $scope.songEmbed = song.song_embed;
            $scope.soundcloud = song.song_embed;
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            console.log('Error fetching');
            $scope.songID = null;
        });
    };
}]);
```

I know it's a problem with the asynchronous nature because when I add this line in the beginning of my song controller:

```
$scope.soundcloud = "https://soundcloud.com/jshigley/shine";
```

It works perfectly fine. I've also noticed that when I spam the play/pause button that DOES come up from the directive, I get multiple console errors of "HTTP 404 Not Found", which leads me to believe it's trying to find a track of undefined url

Since it's a div directive and not a function call I can't use promises such as chaining a then to my $scope.songPromise. I've thought of putting it into a controller and having the controller do something like $timeout for 5 seconds, but I don't think this delays the execution of the DOM.

The soundcloud URL DOES end up getting loaded, but it remains undefined in the eyes of the plangular directive (I've actually encountered lots of these problems with bad timing of loading scope and directives). Any Angular Wizards willing to teach me how to tame the asynchronous nature of AngularJS?

Comment: Have you tried using ngShow for the div that's bound to a value declared after your $http request fulfills a promise?

Comment: The plangular directive code is here: https://github.com/jxnblk/plangular/blob/master/src/plangular.js, it was not developed by me

Comment: Does ngShow prevent the div plangular from executing? I thought it only hide the div, but did not prevent the code from inside from being loaded

Comment: See my answer below. ngShow won't stop plangular from executing, but it WILL prevent the `div` from showing until all of the information has loaded, assuming your $http request is functioning properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $watch in the custom directive to watch when url attributes is changed. 
In

```
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {
```

change from

```
if (src) {
    resolve({ url: src, client_id: client_id }, function(err, res) {
      if (err) { console.error(err); }
      scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.track = createSrc(res);
        if (Array.isArray(res)) {
          scope.tracks = res.map(function(track) {
            return createSrc(track);
          });
        } else if (res.tracks) {
          scope.playlist = res;
          scope.tracks = res.tracks.map(function(track) {
            return createSrc(track);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

to

```
 scope.$watch('attr.plangular', function(newVal) {

    resolve({ url: attr.plangular, client_id: client_id }, function(err, res) {
      if (err) { console.error(err); }
      scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.track = createSrc(res);
        if (Array.isArray(res)) {
          scope.tracks = res.map(function(track) {
            return createSrc(track);
          });
        } else if (res.tracks) {
          scope.playlist = res;
          scope.tracks = res.tracks.map(function(track) {
            return createSrc(track);
          });
        }
      });
    });
 }, true);
```

If you dont want to change the directive then you might want to use ng-if to load that plangular div only when you get the url.

```
<div plangular="{{soundcloud}}" ng-if="haveurl">
```

and in the angular code :

```
}).then(function(successResponse) {
        console.log('Successfully fetched song');
        console.log(successResponse);
        $scope.haveurl = true;
```

Comment: This would be included in the link function in the directive and would automatically changed once detected? I'm a bit new to directives and still don't fully understand them. The directive code for plangular is here: https://github.com/jxnblk/plangular/blob/master/src/plangular.js, sorry for taking up your time, but if you have some, would really appreciate it if you could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-show` like this to only show the `div` once your $http request has been completed.

```
<div ng-show="httpRequestComplete" plangular="{{soundcloud}}">
<button ng-click="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>
<progress ng-value="currentTime / duration || 0">
{{ currentTime / duration || 0 }}
</progress>
</div>

displaySong.controller('song', ['$scope', '$q', '$http', 'fetchSong', function($scope, $http, fetchSong) {
    /* add $q promise library */

    $scope.songID
    $scope.songName;

    var httpRequest = function() {
         var deferred = $q.defer();
         $http({
            method: "post",
            url: fetchSong,
            data: {
                song_id: $scope.songID
            },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function(successResponse) {
            deferred.resolve({response: successResponse});
            console.log('Successfully fetched song', successResponse);
            var song = successResponse.data;
            $scope.songID = song.song_id;
            $scope.songName = song.song_name;
            $scope.songType = song.song_type;
            $scope.songEmbed = song.song_embed;
            $scope.soundcloud = song.song_embed;
        }).error(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    httpRequest().then(function(response) {
          $scope.httpRequestComplete = true;
          console.log('div will show');
    };



}]);
```

I would do something like this that delays the showing of the `div` until `httpRequestComplete = true`, or until your promise ($q) is fulfilled. This will make sure that your `div` isn't loaded until you have the information available.

Comment: i though showing/hiding the div will not prevent the directive to be executed ?

Comment: I see your problem, I believe that @kwan245 has the right idea with using $watch, or alternatively, using ng-if